# Show partial view from different folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

**Is that possible to access partial view which is placed in external folder?**

---

[image]

I want to show a _LoginPartial on a page /Home/Index, but _LoginPartial should be in /Auth.

When I am trying to specify /Home/Index to take this partial from /Auth, I've getting an error.

```
@Html.Partial("/Auth/Login")
```

ErrorLog says that

> Message=The partial view 'Views/Auth/Login' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Home/Auth/Login.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Home/Auth/Login.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Auth/Login.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Auth/Login.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Home/Auth/Login.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Home/Auth/Login.vbhtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Auth/Login.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Auth/Login.vbhtml

So I know that it is trying to find my partial only inside /Home directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the full path to your partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Auth/Login.cshtml")
```